# A Mashal of HaShem as a crazy king and Moshe as His weak-kneed friend?

Tags: talmud-gemara, theology, moshe-rabbeinu, agada-stories-legends, tractate-brachot

The Gemara (Ber. 32a) quotes R' El'azar that when HaShem wanted to destroy Bnei Yisrael and Moshe intervened, it is comparable to a king who beat his son terribly, and the king's friend was at his side but was too afraid to say anything, until the king said, "If my friend weren't here I'd kill you," at which point the friend realized it was up to him and he stepped in and saved the son.

Am I just too Western to think that this story is in any way flattering to any of the parties involved? It just seems to me like the Gemara is comparing HaShem to a terribly disturbed king, and Moshe to a worthless onlooker who doesn't want to get involved even though he could save someone's life. Not to mention that it seems to paint Bnei Yisrael as hapless victims of the crazy king's wrath. I thought HaShem was merciful here because Moshe heroically stepped in to save Bnei Yisrael even though they didn't deserve it. This Gemara seems to convey a very different message!

---

This question is part of the Daf Yomi Challenge

Comment: Does the mashal say that the king beat the son *until he was about to die*? If not, I don't see what your problem is; normal parents punish their children, and Mosheh only wanted to stop the punishment, but no permanent damage would have happened if he didn't

Comment: The Mashal says that he beat him severely and the friend was too afraid to step in, and that the king said he would have killed him if the friend weren't there, _at which point_ the friend "הצילו" - "saved him".

Comment: A mashal would be used to create an extreme presentation so we (as humans) understand the participants and relationships not in an absolute and parallel way but in a way that simplifies it for us. Simply by "equating" hashem to a human king we are doing a disservice.

Comment: @Dan, my question is because I can see an atheist mocking Judaism by making this comparison. But here a Tanna is making the comparison! What's he trying to teach us?

Comment: if hkb"h can be ok with keeping "na'aseh" in bereishis and saying "let them say what they will" then the tanna can take the same approach. In the mashal case, the lashon adam often requires making things obvious and reduced. haters gonna hate no matter what.

Comment: @Dan But what's the lesson?

Comment: relative might? the power of even the meekest to affect the king? the mashal would be less useful if it stated "imagine a case of a generally merciful and benevolent king who, on one day, was in an unusually bad mood and punished his son for something the son did (and for which he deserved a punishment). a good friend fo the king's who often spoke his mind and had in the past swayed the king said something and swayed the king."

Comment: @Dan So...better to learn something negative and offensive about G-d and Moshe and gloss over the nation's failings?

Comment: i don't think one learns something negative or offensive. I think one can more clearly see the power relationship and the chidush of moshe's actions this way.had it been written less "offensively" there would be no lesson about the power of a person to affect the divine will.

Comment: I think this question is worded poorly. Who says the king is "crazy?" Who says the friend is "weak-kneed?" Those are projected qualities that influence the reading of the text. What if we said, "Wise King" and "Humble Friend?" We might read it as a wise king who acted in a way to encourage or even test the friend to see if he would come to the son's aid.

Comment: @Shemmy, I chose this language specifically to allow for the possibility that my understanding is shaped by certain outside influences. The responsibility, however, is on the answerer to explain how, if that is the reason why this Midrash doesn't sit well with me, it is nonetheless imparting a timeless message. Go for it!

Comment: @Dan, you too! ^^^^

Comment: So, is the question here "Am I just too Western to think that this story is in any way flattering to any of the parties involved?" That is the only question I can see here. I think this question calls for an opinion and not a sourced answer.

Comment: @Shemmy Fair enough. Feel free to edit, as I cannot at the moment.